# OneToMany relationship and saving of forms using the Play Framework

Tags: java, model, playframework

I'm a beginner to the Play Framework and am having some difficulty saving form data to two different tables.

When I submit the form the firstName, lastName, and text get saved to the database but I cant seem to find out why the schoolName won't get saved to the schools table. I've spent quite a bit of time watching tutorials and going through other people's sample code and haven't seen a solution. Please if someone could help me out I would really appreciate it.

Here's what I have:

Candidate Model:

```
package models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

@Entity 
public class Candidate extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    public String firstName;

    public String lastName;

    public boolean sponsorshipStatus;

    public boolean proceedToInterview;

    public String text;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="candidate", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<School> schools = new ArrayList<School>();

    /**
     * Generic query helper for entity Candidate with id Long
     */
    public static Model.Finder<Long, Candidate> find = new Model.Finder<Long, Candidate>(
            Long.class, Candidate.class);


}
```

School Model:

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

@Entity 
public class School extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    public String schoolName;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Candidate candidate = new Candidate();




    /**
     * Generic query helper for entity Company with id Long
     */
    public static Model.Finder<Long, School> find = new Model.Finder<Long, School>(
            Long.class, School.class);

}
```

Form template:

```
@(candidateForm: Form[Candidate])

@import helper._

@main("Create Candidate"){

    <h1>Add a Candidate</h1>

    @form(routes.Application.save()) {

        <fieldset>
        ${candidateForm("firstName")}
            @inputText(candidateForm("firstName"), '_label -> "First Name")
            @inputText(candidateForm("lastName"), '_label -> "Last Name")
            @inputText(candidateForm("text"), '_label -> "Text")
            @inputText(candidateForm("schoolName"), '_label -> "School")




        </fieldset>

        <div class="actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Create this computer" class="btn primary"> or 
            <a href="" class="btn">Cancel</a> 
        </div>
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package controllers;

import static play.data.Form.form;
import models.Candidate;
import play.data.Form;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.createForm;
import views.html.index;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

    /**
     * Display the 'new candidate form'.
     */
    public static Result create() {
        Form<Candidate> candidateForm = form(Candidate.class);
        return ok(views.html.createForm.render(candidateForm));
    }

    /**
     * Handle the 'new computer form' submission 
     */
    public static Result save() {
        Form<Candidate> candidateForm = form(Candidate.class).bindFromRequest();
        if(candidateForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(createForm.render(candidateForm));
        }
        candidateForm.get().save();
        flash("success", "Computer " + candidateForm.get().firstName + " has been created");
        return redirect("/candidates/new");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

Why is the school list private? I don't think that changes things but worth a look.

It probably isn't saving because it's a collection and you don't provide any direction for the program to either look up an existing school (and pass the id and I think have the field be called something like schools.id) and add it to the collection or create a new school and then add it to the model table and then also to the collection. I work mostly in play 1.x and your's seems to be 2.x so I'm not familiar with the template syntax but if you look up in the play 1.x tutorial I remember there being an example about how to work with relationships and forms.

Writing this from a train station so can't look up the links but hopefully this gets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

candidate Form . get().save(); where is save method.check your controller ,may be you have a syntax mistake too.check for compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

Your form has this:

@inputText(candidateForm("schoolName"), '_label -> "School")

But the Candidate class doesn't have shoolName property.  Have a look at the Computer-Database sample that comes with Play.  They have a form for Computer that includes a list of Company names.  Should be helpful to you.